# Name for a figure bounded by algebraic sets

Tags: algebraic-geometry, terminology, discrete-geometry

Is there an established named for the class of solid figures in $\mathbb{R}^n$ whose boundaries consist of finitely many sections of algebraic sets of codimension 1? Something like 'algebrotope' (and 'algebrogon', 'algebrohedron', etc) seems clear and sensical to me, but this returns no search results. I'd like to talk about 'linear algebrotopes' (i.e. polytopes) and 'quadratic algebrotopes' (such as disks) and such.

Comment: People call sets determined by polynomial equalities and inequalities *semialgebraic*.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Ah thank you very much! :) I'll close the question with this answer as soon as I am able.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @Mariano Suárez-Álvarez's comment, such sets are known as *semialgebraic sets*.